# Different colors in cv2 and QPixmap/QImage

Tags: opencv, image-processing, pyqt6, qimage, qpixmap

I am trying to build a simple image editor app using Python and PyQt6. At the moment, TIFF images are loaded using cv2.imread(). Then, the user can make several adjustments (contrast, colors, etc.). Finally, the images are saved using cv2.imwrite(). This part works just fine.
For the GUI, the image is converted in a QImage and then to a QPixmap, which is then displayed on a QLabel on the GUI.

Problem: The colors in the exported images slightly differ from the image being displayed on the GUI. The differences are subtile. But, obviously, for an image editor app I expect the preview image to look identical to the final output.

The problem is easily visible if I run the following code:

```py
image_data = cv2.imread("Color_Adobe.tif")
cv2.imshow("CV2", image_data)

#convert to QImage:
h,w,_ = image_data.shape
bytesPerLine = 3 * w
image = QImage(image_data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
pixmap = QPixmap(image)

#set pixmap to QLabel
label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
```

The image being loaded here is a .TIF image of a color chart. The output I get is the following:

CV2 vs Pixmap Output:
[image: CV2 vs Pixmap Output]

Above is the cv2.imshow() output, below is the QLabel with the Pixmap in my GUI. As you can see, the colors are rendered quite differently. In general, the pixmap output seems slightly more reddish.

Looking at the red square on the bottom left, I get these readings with DigitalColorMeter on my screen (Mac):
CV2:    236 56 30
Pixmap: 255 0 0
(RGB)

I assume this has something to do with color spaces which don't match - but I just can't get my head around what exactly is happening.

How can I make sure that the pixmap is displayed in the same way as the cv2.imshow() output? Or is there a different/better way of showing the image in the GUI?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the issue. That "control strip" should show basic colors as a reference, and the bottom one returns correct values: the bottom left square is pure red (255, 0, 0), the second is pure green (0, 255, 0), etc. So, the "error" is in the way cv2 shows colors, possibly because it doesn't properly interface with the underlying color space capabilities of macos. But, maybe I didn't understand your problem and you're referring to how you see the images on your screen.

Comment: The problem is that the same .TIF file (the color strip) is displayed differently when viewed via cv.imshow() or via QPixmap. Via imshow() I get the result on the top, with QPixmap the result on the bottom (the image is a screenshot). cv2 shows the "correct" colors, Pixmap shows colors which are slightly different.

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is either incomplete or inaccurate. From where does that tif file come from? What colors should it display? Most importantly, the colors of the last row should *be* standard colors (with the first square being a "real" red, etc.) or are they some representation of "altered" colors (for instance, due to color correction for video processing)? With "correct" colors, are you referring to what you *physically see with your eyes* on the screen, or what DigitalColorMeter shows?

Comment: Also, consider that what you see on your screen is not what we could see on ours (and what our OS *try* to display). For instance, on my computer, the red square on top (cv) has rgb(255, 2, 0), while you report that it has rgb(236, 56, 30). The fourth square in the middle ("dark magenta") for me reports (183, 53, 127) on top and (198, 25, 131). Please, try to be detailed about your problem.

Comment: Ok. The color chart I show in my example is just for demonstration purposes. I can take any image, and load it via cv2.imread(). Then, I show it via cv2.imshow(). After that, I convert the image to a QPixmap, as shown in my code, and I display this QPixmap as well. Now I have two images on my screen: The one via imshow() and the one via Pixmap, right? These two images now look different on my screen. Both to my eyes, and also to the ColorMeter. So, during the conversion from my cv2 image to the pixmap, something happened to the colors. I am trying to find out what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally figured it out. Turns out that when you use cv2.imshow(), the image will be displayed using the monitors specific ICC profile. However, when displaying the same image (on the same screen) via a Pixmap, standard sRGB color space is used. To solve that, I first convert the image to a PIL Image, load the ICC profiles (sRGB and Monitor specific) and convert the colorSpaces. Then convert to Pixmap and display on my GUI. This way, the Pixmap finally looks identical to the imshow() output.

```
        image_data = cv2.imread("Color_Adobe.tif")

        #CV2 Output
        cv2.imshow("CV2", image_data)

        image_data = cv2.cvtColor(image_data, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        
        PIL_image_sRGB = PIL.Image.fromarray(image_data)

        #Path to sRGB ICC Profile
        src_profile_path = "/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/sRGB.icc"

        # Path to Monitors specific ICC Profile
        dst_profile_path = "/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays/HP U32 4K HDR-11C013E4-4731-AAD9-78F8-9D92871BECD3.icc"

        #Open profiles in PIL
        dst_profile = PIL.ImageCms.getOpenProfile(dst_profile_path)
        src_profile = PIL.ImageCms.getOpenProfile(src_profile_path)

        #convert color spaces to new ICC
        PIL_image_ICC = PIL.ImageCms.profileToProfile(PIL_image_sRGB, src_profile, dst_profile)

        #convert back to numpy array
        image_data = np.array(PIL_image_ICC)


        #convert to QImage
        h,w,_ = image_data.shape
        bytesPerLine = 3 * w
        image = QImage(image_data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format.Format_RGB888)
        
        #convert to pixmap
        pixmap = QPixmap(image)    
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

Comment: Sorry, I was gathering references for a reply, but didn't have enough time to accurately do it yet. The issue, indeed, is the different way images are shown by opencv and Qt. In theory, at least in programming sense (and as far as I know), Qt is the more accurate one, since colors are "drawn as intended" for the painted source: for instance red (rgb 255, 0 0) is finally drawn as such, with color correction applied on the painted surface, which also seems consistent with your original test. Now, the problem is to understand what you actually want to "show", while still keeping source data. »

Comment: » It depends on the requirements of your program, but a correct approach should theoretically provide the image *and* the color space as separate contexts, not alter the image data *for* the color space. In that way, you can properly provide image editing with the correct source data and still *show* it using the required color spaces. Note that, since 5.14, Qt provides classes and functions for these aspects: a QColorSpace can be created from the `fromIccProfile` static function, then you can get a QColorTransform from *another* similarly created QColorSpace and eventually apply it to a »

Comment: » QImage with `applyColorTransform()`. Also consider that one of the important reasons for which Qt provides QImage and QPixmap classes is that the former is a *data consistent* representation of the image, while QPixmap is based on the display device capabilities provided by the OS. Simply put, QImage is more like an object tree of an HTML page, while QPixmap is a screenshot of it taken from a browser. This is also why a QGuiApplication is required to create a QPixmap, but that is not necessary for a QImage. Also note that showing a "screen-consistent" image *could* possibly break attempts »

Comment: » to "grab" a color from the *displayed* image using standard methods, for instance if you want to provide an "eye-dropper-like" tool, which is normally achieved using `QScreen.grabWindow()` and accessing the related pixel data. I'm not completely sure about this possible issue, as I've never used color spaces, but since `grabWindow()` returns a QPixmap, I don't know if it considers color spaces when converting it back to a QImage. So, if you eventually need such a feature, you should consider these aspects and eventually provide different behavior when the target is the "shown" image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answers!! Yes, when I display programmatically pure red (255,0,0), it shows as such in the QPixmap ("100% red"). Once I export it via imwrite() or show it via imshow(), it's a different color because it is passed through the monitors ICC profile first. That's why I need to adjust the Pixmap to the colors that are finally present in the exported image. I looked into QColorSpace but couldn't really get how I can import an ICC profile "directly" from a path there.

Comment: It seems only possible from an array, which requires that I already have the ICC data imported somehow. Do you know how to accomplish that? Otherwise, I will probably just stick with the PIL workaround for now. My bigger problem now is how to programmatically detect which ICC profile is currently used on the user's monitor. At the moment I just hardcoded the paths to the ICC profiles, but of course, that should happen automatically depending on the user's screen setup. Any idea how to do that for MacOS machines?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use macOS. About the QColorSpace, the "array" you're referring to is a *byte array*, and in that context it is the raw data loaded from the file: you should be able to do `colorSpace = QColorSpace.fromIccProfile(QByteArray(open(profile_path, 'rb').read()))`